# can't show firebird data in php-ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: firebird, internal-server-error, ubuntu-server

my dataTable can't show data from firebird database.
it's happen after I move to new server (old server have hard disk damage). all php data and mysql database already backed up then restore to new server. But, one of my php page can't show data from firebird database (its from another server).

the strange point is why in my old server it can show but in the new one it can't ?

my server `os` is `ubuntu server 12.04` then I try :

`sudo apt-get install php5-firebird --> i get firebird2.5`

but, my php file still can't show firebird data.
`500 internal server error`

my old server is `ubuntu server 10.04` and have installed `firebird2.1`.
is there any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can fix this trouble, if move anything to new server for this case, i must prepare:

1. sudo apt-get install php5-firebird
2. sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-server-common
3. sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-classic
4. sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
5. Add ServerName localhost, save and exit
6. sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
7. reload the page

Then, all can work normally.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install php5-interbase