# PHP5 execute ./configure command

Tags: php, ubuntu, firebird

How can I execute following command:

./configure --with-pdo-firebird

I need to configure php5 (installed on my ubuntu) to accept firebird connections.

So now I need to execute the ./configure command. How can I do that on my ubuntu server?

Comment: Unless I am totally missing something won't you just go "./configure.sh --with-pdo-firebird" when you are in the right directory in the terminal?

Comment: I don't want to reinstall my php.. So now I have 1 directory /etc/php5 and there I can't execute ./configure.sh

Comment: And why can't you? Is there a `error`? Maybe you need to `sudo`? Is the `.sh` file missing? Specifics help a lot

Comment: How do you know you need to execute that command? Are you going thru specific tutorial or how-to? If yes, which one? That command line is used to configure source code, next step would be compiling and then installing.

Comment: I don't know if you need to execute it, you asked how you to execute it and to execute a .sh you run it as "./the_file.sh". Here is a guide on how to setup php5 with firebird http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2009/04/php5-and-firebird-pdo-on-ubuntu-hardy.html

Comment: is there a special reason why you believe you need to build your own php instead of using one from the repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this FAQ from Firebird SQL website: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq234/

This is related question: [can't show firebird data in php-ubuntu server 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945516/cant-show-firebird-data-in-php-ubuntu-server-12-04)